# Problem reading and searching file in Python

Tags: python, regex, encoding

I'm trying to read and do basic parsing on some log files but for some reason the files seem to be plagued with special characters or there is something I'm doing wrong with encoding.

When I open the log file on Notepad, NP++, Pycharm or other it looks fine, I can search and get the results I'd expect. However when I try to search from the script it doesn't find anything. Furthermore, if I run the script in PyCharm and print the whole text when I search in the PyCharm's "Run" tab it doesn't return what I'd expect either, even though the text is right there. Check Image below:

[image: Doesn't find word "Bucket" even though is clearly present multiple times.]

Finally if I copy text from the Run tab and paste it to the editor it seems to be filled with special characters. If I check file encoding is cp1252.

This simple regex which should return many matches returns empty list:

```
with open('output.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
   text = fh.read()
pattern = re.compile(r'Bucket', flags=re.MULTILINE)
matches = (re.findall(pattern, text))
```

I tried encoding and decoding, even reading the file with cp1252 encoding and writing contents to a new file with utf-8 encoding like so:

```
with open('original.log', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as fh1:
    print(fh1.encoding)
    temptext = fh1.read()
    temptext.encode('cp1252').decode('Latin-1')
    fh2 = open('output.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    fh2.write(temptext)
    fh2.close()
```

None of that worked. Anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had it all wrong. The actual encoding of the file was utf-16. So adding that to the open statement solved it `with open('original.log'), 'r', encoding='utf-16')` works fine.